# (When) can you use dictionary form with 間? / 辞書形と「間」は（どんな時に）一緒に使えますか？

Tags: tense, time

I've just learned 間･間に, as in:

> 私はビーンに**いる間**、写真をたくさん取りたいですよ。
>
> ジョンは出かけ**ている間**、ビールを飲みました。

All the examples on my grammar sheet use present-continuous form (～ている) or いる. (These are my own examples, though.) So my question is twofold:

1. Can you use present-tense dictionary form (e.g. 出かける) with 間?
2. If so, what time-frame would it indicate; when would the action take place?

---

**和訳**

私はつい最近「間・間に」を習いました。例えば、

> 私はビーンに**いる間**、写真をたくさん撮りたいですよ。
>
> ジョンは出かけ**ている間**、ビールを飲みました。

私の文法プリントに載っている例文は全部現在進行形（～ている）か「いる」を使っています（上のは自作の例文ですが）。そこで、二つの質問があります。

1. 現在の辞書形（例：出かける）を「間」と一緒に使うことはできますか？
2. 使えるとしたら、前後関係はどうなるのですか？動作はいつ行われるのですか？

Comment: Why have you added a Japanese translation to the question? I don't take particular issue with it, I just don't see what it adds, unless there's a new site-wide policy I'm not aware of.

Comment: I think this question is rather hard to answer perfectly. I wanted to attract native speakers who'll drop by this site or see Japanese Google so that they can leave their opinions. Please see [here](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/encouraging-participation-from-native-japanese-speakers-translating-posts) for further explanation.

Comment: Maybe we should add furigana to questions with 間, because it can be hard for learners to know if it's read あいだ or ま, or even かん.

Answer (score 2):

間 stands for "while," "during."

So it stands to reason that you use it with a verb indicating some duration, as in 居る間, 出かけている間 (= while staying, while staying out).

I would not say 出かける間, as I doubt 出かける is an action with duration.

***  Added the 21st June, 2015  ***

I have no ideal why someone downvoted my answer.

I would like to stress that 出かける means "to go out" and refers to the *action* of "going out". Do you say "while I go out?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use 出かける間 from the moment when you try to leave home, to the moment when you get out. In addition, you can still use 出かけている間 for the same situation. The action in the main clause is done during that moment. e.g. 私がちょうど出かける間にネコに家に入られたようだ。(By the way, what the speaker in the first sentence is whining for, regaring taking picture?)

Comment: Well, you've answered the first question, but I confess I'm confused about the difference between 出かけている間 and 出かける間 here.

Comment: Unlike 出かける間、出かけてる間 can stand for the time when you are out before arriving home again.